dynamically query schema in postgres
how to use postgres sql script with dynamic schema name as below within pgadmin to batch change table ownership under a certain schema?
(declare?) schema = 'x'
ALTER [schema].table1 OWNER TO new_user;
ALTER [schema].table2 OWNER TO new_user;
ALTER [schema].table3 OWNER TO new_user;

I do not want to create a function to do this, since it involves granting execute access of this function to the original user of those table (1,2,3), and I do not know who those original owners are, and I would rather let them use this script to change the ownership by themselves.

You may create a do pl/pgsql block that uses dynamic sql.

You can switch the search_path and then skip the schema name in your alter statements entirely: demo at db<>fiddle
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL search_path='x';
ALTER TABLE table1 OWNER TO new_user;
ALTER TABLE table2 OWNER TO new_user;
ALTER TABLE table3 OWNER TO new_user;
COMMIT;

They will now all refer to x.table1, x.table2, x.table3, and thanks to SET LOCAL after the COMMIT the setting goes back to what it was.
As long as it's set to x, it will not affect any other schema, including public or the one named after the current user, which are normally the first two schemas tried when you don't explicitly state the schema the referenced table is in. That's unless you do explicitly schema-qualify the identifiers.
If you're passing ownership of everything a user owns, you can also use REASSIGN OWNED.
